# How to define a variable in Python

Tags: python

I am a first time learner of Python and i am trying to define the variable a in my function. 
How can i do it? 
Whenever i run this function, it says name 'a' is not defined.
and if there is anything more wrong, where did i get it wrong?

```
n= int(input ("choose your number >2     "))

def J(a,b):
    a = (n)
    b = (n-2)
    for (a) in range (n):
        for (b) in range (n-2):
            if a==b:
                print ()
def J(a,b):
    return math.factorial (a)// math.factorial (b)
size= J(a,b)
if size>40:
    a=input ("the pernutations would fill more than one screeen "
           +"still want to see th`enter code here`em all? yes or no    ")
    if a=="yes":
        print (J(a,b))
    if a=="no":`enter code here`
        print ()
```

Comment: There problem is here: `size= J(a,b)`. Scripts run top-to-bottom and `a` has not been defined by that point. The name doesn't exist when you _call_ the function - it doesn't matter if you then do `a = (n)` inside the function (the parentheses are pointless here btw). On the other hand, `b` _never_ exists in the global scope where you actually call the function

Comment: why is `J(a,b)` defined twice ?

Comment: To add to @roganjosh 's comment. The `a = (n)` is local to J()'s scope.

Comment: If not done already you should work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `a` and `b` or replace them with values. They act as placeholders for the values that are being inputted as your function caller. The `a` and `b` in the function are only local to the function, where when you call it, it sets the argument as the variable and treats it that way inside the function.

```
a = "value" #replace with your value, if not string, remove quotes
b = "value"  
size = J(a,b)
```

or

```
size = J(value1, value2)
```

Comment: ya. I should definitely go through the tutorial..  I meant to set a as variable n and b as variable n-2 in order to shown all possible permutations of the function.

Comment: @JeremyKong if it answers your question, don't forget to click the check mark